# how and where do I download the itextpdf jar file

Tags: jar, download, itext

I'm trying to download the jar file for itextpdf but it seems to be very confusing and at least to me to be very obscure.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can just go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/latest/download

the file you download will be a zip file, you need unzip it and grab the itextpdf-5.5.6.jar. its size is around 2087KB,  you may need itext-pdfa-5.5.6.jar or itext-xtra-5.5.6.jar but itextpdf-5.5.6.jar is the core one.I don't think you need worry about other jars.